# Showing an isomorphism of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Consider the ideal $I=(1+2x)\cdot \Bbb Z[x]$ in the polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[x]$. I am trying to show that $\Bbb Z[x]/I$ is isomorphic to $R=\{\frac{a}{2^r}:a\in \Bbb Z, r\in \Bbb N_0\}$.

My approach:

Define a ring homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z[x]\to R$ by $X^r\mapsto (-1)^r \frac{1}{2^{r+1}}$ for $r\in \Bbb N$ and $X^0\mapsto 1$. Then this descends to a homorphism on $\Bbb Z[x]/I$ since $f(1+2x)= 1- 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}=0$.

An inverse to the descent of $f$ is given by $g:R\to \Bbb Z[x]/I$ with $g(\frac{1}{2^r})=(-1)^{r-1}x^{r-1}$

Is this a valid proof?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is good. What you have to show is

1. $f$ is surjective
2. $\ker f=I$

Surjectivity should be easy enough. Since the map $f$ satisfies $f(X)=-\frac{1}{2}$, it is clear that $1+2x\in\ker f$, so $\ker f\supseteq I$. In order to show the converse, suppose $p(x)\in\ker f$. Then write
$$
p(x)=(1+2x)q(x)+r
$$
in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, with $r$ a constant. Then $p(-1/2)=0$ implies $r=0$. Now you just have to prove that $q$ has integer coefficients.

Comment: Didn't I take care of both of those by writing down the inverse $g:R\to \Bbb Z[x]/I$ ?

Comment: @MyNameIs Yes, but you have to care about well-definedness of $g$.

Comment: Oh true. Surjectivity is easy enough. How to show $\ker f\subset I$? So $\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\in \ker f$ means that $$0=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}}$$ Then how can write $\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ as $(1+2x)$ times some other polynomial? @egreg